# How often does the tcpdump save into the file

Tags: usb, tcpdump, unmounting

I've got an question, concerning the tcpdumd. Does it save the data directly in the File you can give it with -w, or does it save when it's stopped? So if it was writing on a usbstick, can I just unmount it and it would just save the whole data on the stick. And is there an option to just unplug it and still write the data on it.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it save the data directly in the File you can give it with -w, or does it save when it's stopped?

By default, it writes the data to the file when the "standard I/O library" buffer it's using fills up.  Those buffers are usually 4K or 8K bytes, so every 4K or 8K bytes, it writes the data to the file.  When it's stopped, it writes out everything it hasn't already written.

In newer versions of tcpdump (built with newer versions of libpcap), the `-U` flag can be used; it tells tcpdump to write out each packet as it's received, even if the buffer isn't yet full.

> So if it was writing on a usbstick, can I just unmount it and it would just save the whole data on the stick.

No.  You should stop tcpdump first, and *then* unmount the USB stick, if you want all the data to be there.

Furthermore, unless you do a forced unmount, the system may refuse to let you unmount the USB stick as long as tcpdump is writing to a file on that stick.  A forced unmount would lose data within tcpdump *and* possibly lose data within the kernel's file system buffers.

> And is there an option to just unplug it and still write the data on it.

If you unplug the USB stick while tcpdump is running, you will lose data within tcpdump and possibly lose data within the kernel's file system buffers.

If you run with `-U`, then the only data you'll lose within tcpdump is any data it's in the *middle* of writing when you unmount or unplug the USB stick, but you'll still lose any data that's in the kernel's file system buffers and not yet written to the USB stick.